# "Make good use of it" synonyms

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, formality

I am applying for a job and I will make real good use of the opportunity it will provide me. Could someone give me a good phrase for the following bold part of the sentence:

I would really appreciate and ***make the best of it*** should I be offered one.

Comment: Use "give my best". *To give one's best is to perform a task as well as possible*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could say "[take advantage of it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+advantage+of)."